# How does the BizTalk Batching Service work?

Tags: biztalk

I am working on a BizTalk EDI project and now was struggling with BizTalk Batching service cannot subscribe my published message in message box

I have created the party and agreement, in the batch config, I set the filter as something like:

```
EDI.ToBeBatched==True 
and BTS.MessageType == MyMessageType
```

But BizTalk kept complaining that my message does not have a subscriber.

When I query the Subscription in Hub, I can find 2 instance subscription related with my batch, but none of these 2 have my customized filter condition.

Could someone show me how the batching service work? i.e.: when a message published in message box, how does the BizTalk batching service know it is belongs to which batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the documentation on this is pretty complete: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226413.aspx

It explains what that Filter is for and how to route messages to the Batching instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter should NOT have the "EDI.ToBeBatched" property set to true.  Biztalk will set this to true for you in the EDI Receive pipeline **when your specified filter conditions (at the party level) are met.**

To be more specific, the "BatchMarker" component of the EDIReceive pipeline will set subscription conditions necessary for the special batching orchestration instance (running in the Biztalk EDI Application) to subscribe to, batch and deliver your EDI Messages.